# AngularJS Unit Test crashing. Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am attempting to do my first unit test in AngularJS and it has not been going well. I am unsuccessfully attempting to run a unit test example that I found on the web. After quite a few hours, I need some help.

I have put the code on Plunker. Can anyone help to get it going?
https://plnkr.co/edit/D7VwLfoFp0QzhobrKN9f

It is big for Plunker but the ONLY files of concern is: 
index.html , module.js , controller.js , unitTest.js  .

index.html contains

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.3/jasmine.min.css">  

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.3/jasmine.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.3/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.3/boot.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

module.js contains:

```
myTable = angular.module('myTable', ['ngMdIcons', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

controller.js contains the controller

```
myTable.controller('tableCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', '$timeout', '$filter', 'orderByFilter', '$uibModal', 'factGlobal', 'factApp', 'factMainTbl', '$window', '$element', '$log', '$http', 'APIService', '$document',  
    function ($scope, $sce, $timeout, $filter, orderBy, $uibModal, factGlobal, factApp, factMainTbl, $window, $element, $log, $http, APIService, $document) {
```

where
factGlobal, factApp, etc. are services in the perspective *.js files

At the end of the controller is the function I am trying to test.
Found it on the web.

```
    // ===============================================================================================================
    // Eample unit test function
    // ===============================================================================================================
    $scope.sum = function () {
        $scope.z = $scope.x + $scope.y;
    };
}]) // end controller
```

unitTest.js <<<<< CONTAINS UNIT TEST THAT IS CRASHING with the error
    calculatorExample encountered a declaration exception

```
describe('calculatorExample', function () { 
    beforeEach(
        // module.js contains  
        //   // myTable = angular.module('myTable', ['ngMdIcons', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);  
        module('myTable', ['ngMdIcons', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap'] 
        // Crashes  
        //  module('myTable', [] // myTable = angular.module('myTable', ['ngMdIcons', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);  
        )  
        );  

    // Controller:  
    //   myTable.controller('tableCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', '$timeout', '$filter', 'orderByFilter', '$uibModal', 'factGlobal', 'factApp', 'factMainTbl', '$window', '$element', '$log', '$http', 'APIService', '$document',  
    //    function ($scope, $sce, $timeout, $filter, orderBy, $uibModal, factGlobal, factApp, factMainTbl, $window, $element, $log, $http, APIService, $document) {  
    var $controller;  
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {  
        $controller = _$controller_;  
    }));  

    describe('sumExample', function () {  
        it('1 + 1 should equal 2', function () {  
            var $scope = {};  
            var controller = $controller('tableCtrl', { $scope: $scope });  
            //  All these have crashed  
            //    $scope, $sce, $timeout, $filter, 'orderBy', $uibModal, 'factGlobal', 'factApp', 'factMainTbl', $window, $element, $log, $http, 'APIService', $document  
            //    $scope, $sce, $timeout, $filter, orderBy, $uibModal, factGlobal, factApp, factMainTbl, $window, $element, $log, $http, APIService, $document  
            //    $scope: $scope, $sce:$sce, $timeout:$timeout, $filter:$filter, orderBy:orderBy, $uibModal:$uibModal, factGlobal:factGlobal, factApp:factApp, factMainTbl:factMainTbl, $window:$window, $element:$element, $log:$log, $http:$http, APIService:APIService, $document:$document  
            $scope.x = 1;  
            $scope.y = 2;  
            $scope.sum();  
            expect($scope.z).toBe(3);  
        });  
    });  
});
```

When I get it running I will correct it on Plunker and make it public.  Perhaps it will also be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unit test crash crashed because the various controller object ('$scope', '$sce', '$timeout', etc.) were not mapped correctly to the unit test with a LOCAL variable in the unit test.

It is corrected on Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/D7VwLfoFp0QzhobrKN9f?p=preview

```
// controller.js
myTable.controller('tableCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', '$timeout', '$filter', 'orderByFilter', '$uibModal', 'factGlobal', 'factApp', 'factMainTbl', '$window', '$element', '$log', '$http', 'APIService', '$document',  
    function ($scope, $sce, $timeout, $filter, orderBy, $uibModal, factGlobal, factApp, factMainTbl, $window, $element, $log, $http, APIService, $document) {  


// unitTest.js
describe('Hello World example ', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myTable'));
    var tableCtrl;
    var scope;
    var sce;
    var timeout;
    var filter;
    var orderByLocal;
    var uibModalLocal;
    var factGlobalLocal;
    var factAppLocal;
    var factMainTblLocal;
    var window;
    var element;
    var log;
    var http;
    var APIServiceLocal;
    var document;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        tableCtrl = $controller('tableCtrl', {
            $scope: scope, $sce: sce, $timeout: timeout, $filter: filter, orderBy: orderByLocal, $uibModal: uibModalLocal, factGlobal: factGlobalLocal, factApp: factAppLocal, factMainTbl: factMainTblLocal, $window: window, $element: element, $log: log, $http: http, APIService: APIServiceLocal, $document: document
        });
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically there was a issue in the order of library. also used latest version of angular-mocks.js.

look at my updated plunker.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Tz0ZUZmPR6Nox8X37crj?p=preview

```
myTable.controller('tableCtrl', ['$scope',
function ($scope) {


    // ===============================================================================================================
    // Eample unit test function
    // ===============================================================================================================
    $scope.sum = function () {
        $scope.z = $scope.x + $scope.y;
    };

}]) // end controller
```

Comment: I updated the angular-mocks.js version to the latest.  What do you mean by "order of library"?  The *.js libraries or within the unitTest.js?

Comment: check my index.html. You need to reference the javascript libraries in certain order.

Comment: Also please check the change in Unittest.js file and controller files

Comment: Quickly tried *.js files but screwed up the whole thing.  I now understand what you said about the order of *.js files in Index.js  I'll retry tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: I ordered Index *.js files as you said. Put jQuery before Bootstrap through.  Copied unitTest.js from you.  Crashes. I retried other ways. Crashes.  Can you show me unitTest.js with my controller instead of gutted your controller.js? Thanks @Kalyan